# Swift: Image Preprocessing in CoreML: Resize and Transpose

Tags: swift, image-processing, coreml, coremltools

I need to preprocess the UIImage object before feeding to my model.

The model requires 2 transforms:

1. resize to 224,224
2. transpose to CHW

I searched and found there are 2 approaches:

1. do the preprocessing in Swift
2. add the operations to the AI model using Coremltools

I only managed to find how to do the resize in Swift, but have no idea how to do transpose to make sure the image has data format in CHW.

Also have no idea how to see the data format(CHW or HWC) from UIImage.

How to transpose and how to view the data format?

Answer (score 0):

Setup Image input type and don't worry about sizes and data formats. Have clear API.

Example:

```
image_input = ct.ImageType(name="input_image", shape=(224,224))
model = ct.convert(traced_model, inputs=[image_input])
```

Comment: thanks @Dmytro, I saw this for TF and Torch, but I use ONNX. is there a way to set it up like what you showed me here?

Comment: You can create mediate model using PyTorch which can convert MTLArray to CVPixelBuffer and then to CIImage/UIImage.

https://dmytrohrebeniuk.medium.com/convert-mlmultiarray-to-image-for-pytorch-models-without-performance-lags-df93de9d2d46

Comment: did you mean use my ONNX model to create a PyTorch model?? how to do that?

Comment: No, create PyTorch model as in article, after send your's ONNX model output to PyTorch model. Then you can get image in clear and way.